# Add hyphen to clean URL with htaccess

Tags: apache, query-string, clean-urls

I am following the single page approach for my website, all the GET requests were built like: **index.php?ressource=product&identifier=5**

To achieve clean URLs, I have found a generator which created this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on$ [NC]
RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP_HOST}/ [L] HTTPS_HOST ???

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ ?ressource=$1&identifier=$2&action=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z]+)$ ?ressource=$1&identifier=$2 [L]

#EOF
```

I have added the first three lines to force the user's client to go to my https site.

Now I also would like to have a hyphen within the identifier value, something like **article/terms-of-service**.

I did some research and I need to either use the NC, QSA or both flags, but whenever I add one of those flags I get the Server Error 500.

Comment: `NC` is ignore case, `QSA` retains the previous query string

Comment: @hjpotter92 okay, the other rule i tried is `RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ ?ressource=$1 [L]` which only results in an 500 internal server error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i have found the solution to add hyphen within the clean urls:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-üA-Ü\-]+)/([a-z]+)$ ?ressource=$1&identifier=$2&kwargs=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)/([0-9a-üA-Ü\-\%\s]+)$ ?ressource=$1&identifier=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ ?ressource=$1 [L]
```

the hyphen character had to be added to the regular expression